# WPF DataBinding interaction with ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

In my ListBox I have controls that need to bind to properties in my ItemsSource as well as in my Viewmodel. The buttons as you can see need to do both. The only way I seem to be able to do this is quite ugly (see the IsEnabled property binding to the view's view model). I was wondering what the best way to do this was.

EDIT: To clarify I want to bind the IsEnabled property to CanRemove.

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding CanRemove}"></Button>
```

This does not work

Thanks

XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="songListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding SongList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSongAndNumber, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanged="songListBox_SelectionChanged" Tag="{Binding OperationState, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>

                .......

                <Label Grid.Column="1" Width="200" Height="40" Content="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Width="200" Height="40" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                <Button Grid.Column="5" x:Name="btnMerge" Click="btnMerge_Click" Content="{Binding Tag, Converter={StaticResource ButtonConverter}, ElementName=songListBox}" IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext,Converter={StaticResource EnableConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:AlbumTrackAssociationView}}}">
                    <Button.Visibility>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource B2V}">
                            <Binding Path="Number"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="songListBox"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Button.Visibility>
                </Button>

                <Button Grid.Column="7" x:Name="btnDelete" Click="btnDelete_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext, Converter={StaticResource EnableConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:AlbumTrackAssociationView}}}">Delete
                    <Button.Visibility>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource B2V}">
                            <Binding Path="Number"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="songListBox"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Button.Visibility>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

ViewModel

```
public class AlbumTrackAssociationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public class SongAndNumber : ViewModelBase
    {

        private string number;

        public string Number
        {
            get { return number; }
            set { 
                number = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Number");
            }
        }

        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    private int _numberOfSongs { get; set; }

    public bool CanRemove
    {
        get { return SongList != null && (SongList.Count <= _numberOfSongs ? false : true); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SongAndNumber> SongList { get; set; }
}
```

Converter

```
public class ItemButtonConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        AlbumTrackAssociationViewModel vm = (AlbumTrackAssociationViewModel)value;
        return vm.CanRemove;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need converter at all when you can access ViewModel directly using **`RelativeSource`** markup extension. This should work:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.CanRemove,
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}"/>
```

Since DataContext of ListBox points to viewModel instance, above posted code will work.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for. Makes sense and works.

Comment: but this is not the way you should go when you do MVVM. a button should have a Command binding

Answer (score 1):

when you do mvvm and wanna use button then you should use DelegateCommand or RelayCommand. if you use this then you just have to implement the ICommand properly (CanExecute!) the Command binding to the button will handle IsEnabled for you.

```
  <Button Command="{Binding MyRemoveCommand}"></Button>
```

cs.

```
  public ICommand MyRemoveCommand {get;set;}

  this.MyRemoveCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.RemoveCommandExecute, this.CanRemoveCommandExecute);

  private bool CanRemoveCommandExecute()
  {
      return this.CanRemove;
  }

  private bool RemoveCommandExecute()
  {
      if(!this.CanRemoveCommandExecute)
        return;

     //execution logic here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see in your MVVM there is a bool "CanRemove". You can bind this to your buttons visibility with the already [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is provided by .NET